# Merging a list of time-range tuples that have overlapping time-ranges

Tags: python, algorithm, merge

I have a list of tuples where each tuple is a `(start-time, end-time)`. I am trying to merge all overlapping time ranges and return a list of distinct time ranges.
For example

```
[(1, 5), (2, 4), (3, 6)] --->  [(1,6)]
[(1, 3), (2, 4), (5, 8)] --->  [(1, 4), (5,8)]
```

Here is how I implemented it.

```
# Algorithm
# initialranges: [(a,b), (c,d), (e,f), ...]
# First we sort each tuple then whole list.
# This will ensure that a<b, c<d, e<f ... and a < c < e ... 
# BUT the order of b, d, f ... is still random
# Now we have only 3 possibilities
#================================================
# b<c<d: a-------b           Ans: [(a,b),(c,d)]
#                  c---d
# c<=b<d: a-------b          Ans: [(a,d)]
#               c---d
# c<d<b: a-------b           Ans: [(a,b)]
#         c---d
#================================================
def mergeoverlapping(initialranges):
    i = sorted(set([tuple(sorted(x)) for x in initialranges]))

    # initialize final ranges to [(a,b)]
    f = [i[0]]
    for c, d in i[1:]:
        a, b = f[-1]
        if c<=b<d:
            f[-1] = a, d
        elif b<c<d:
            f.append((c,d))
        else:
            # else case included for clarity. Since 
            # we already sorted the tuples and the list
            # only remaining possibility is c<d<b
            # in which case we can silently pass
            pass
    return f
```

I am trying to figure out if

1. Is the a an built-in function in some python module that can do this more efficiently? or
2. Is there a more pythonic way of accomplishing the same goal?

Your help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A few ways to make it more efficient, Pythonic:

1. Eliminate the `set()` construction, since the algorithm should prune out duplicates during in the main loop.
2. If you just need to iterate over the results, use `yield` to generate the values.
3. Reduce construction of intermediate objects, for example: move the `tuple()` call to the point where the final values are produced, saving you from having to construct and throw away extra tuples, and reuse a list `saved` for storing the current time range for comparison.

Code:

```
def merge(times):
    saved = list(times[0])
    for st, en in sorted([sorted(t) for t in times]):
        if st <= saved[1]:
            saved[1] = max(saved[1], en)
        else:
            yield tuple(saved)
            saved[0] = st
            saved[1] = en
    yield tuple(saved)

data = [
    [(1, 5), (2, 4), (3, 6)],
    [(1, 3), (2, 4), (5, 8)]
    ]

for times in data:
    print list(merge(times))
```

Answer (score 2):

> *Sort tuples then list, if t1.right>=t2.left => merge
> and restart with the new list, ...*

## -->

```
def f(l, sort = True):
    if sort:
        sl = sorted(tuple(sorted(i)) for i in l)
    else:
        sl = l
    if len(sl) > 1:
        if sl[0][1] >= sl[1][0]:
            sl[0] = (sl[0][0], sl[1][1])
            del sl[1]
            if len(sl) < len(l):
                return f(sl, False)
    return sl
```

Comment: This algorithm doesn't work if there are non mergeable ranges at the beginning, for example with [(6,11), (13, 40), (33, 44)].

Answer (score 1):

The sort part: use standard sorting, it compares tuples the right way already.

```
sorted_tuples = sorted(initial_ranges)
```

The merge part. It eliminates duplicate ranges, too, so no need for a `set`. Suppose you have `current_tuple` and `next_tuple`.

```
c_start, c_end = current_tuple
n_start, n_end = next_tuple
if n_start <= c_end: 
  merged_tuple = min(c_start, n_start), max(c_end, n_end)
```

I hope the logic is clear enough.

To peek next tuple, you can use indexed access to `sorted tuples`; it's a wholly known sequence anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Sort all boundaries then take all pairs where a boundary end is followed by a boundary start.

```
def mergeOverlapping(initialranges):
    def allBoundaries():
        for r in initialranges:
            yield r[0], True
            yield r[1], False

    def getBoundaries(boundaries):
        yield boundaries[0][0]
        for i in range(1, len(boundaries) - 1):
            if not boundaries[i][1] and boundaries[i + 1][1]:
                yield boundaries[i][0]
                yield boundaries[i + 1][0]
        yield boundaries[-1][0]

    return getBoundaries(sorted(allBoundaries()))
```

Hm, not that beautiful but was fun to write at least!

EDIT: Years later, after an upvote, I realised my code was wrong! This is the new version just for fun:

```
def mergeOverlapping(initialRanges):
    def allBoundaries():
        for r in initialRanges:
            yield r[0], -1
            yield r[1], 1

    def getBoundaries(boundaries):
        openrange = 0
        for value, boundary in boundaries:
            if not openrange:
                yield value
            openrange += boundary
            if not openrange:
                yield value

    def outputAsRanges(b):
        while b:
            yield (b.next(), b.next())

    return outputAsRanges(getBoundaries(sorted(allBoundaries())))
```

Basically I mark the boundaries with -1 or 1 and then sort them by value and only output them when the balance between open and closed braces is zero.

Answer (score 1):

Late, but might help someone looking for this. I had a similar problem but with dictionaries. Given a list of time ranges, I wanted to find overlaps and merge them when possible. A little modification to @samplebias answer led me to this:

**Merge function:**

```
def merge_range(ranges: list, start_key: str, end_key: str):
    ranges = sorted(ranges, key=lambda x: x[start_key])
    saved = dict(ranges[0])

    for range_set in sorted(ranges, key=lambda x: x[start_key]):
        if range_set[start_key] <= saved[end_key]:
            saved[end_key] = max(saved[end_key], range_set[end_key])
        else:
            yield dict(saved)
            saved[start_key] = range_set[start_key]
            saved[end_key] = range_set[end_key]
    yield dict(saved)
```

**Data:**

```
data = [
    {'start_time': '09:00:00', 'end_time': '11:30:00'},
    {'start_time': '15:00:00', 'end_time': '15:30:00'},
    {'start_time': '11:00:00', 'end_time': '14:30:00'},
    {'start_time': '09:30:00', 'end_time': '14:00:00'}
]
```

**Execution:**

```
print(list(merge_range(ranges=data, start_key='start_time', end_key='end_time')))
```

**Output:**

```
[
    {'start_time': '09:00:00', 'end_time': '14:30:00'},
    {'start_time': '15:00:00', 'end_time': '15:30:00'}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

When using Python 3.7, following the suggestion given by [“RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration” every time I try to run app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51700960/runtimeerror-generator-raised-stopiteration-every-time-i-try-to-run-app), the method `outputAsRanges` from @UncleZeiv should be:

```
    def outputAsRanges(b):
        while b:
            try:
                yield (next(b), next(b))
            except StopIteration:
                return
```