# Sort and Merge two list of lists

Tags: python

I have two lists,

```
[[1, 2], [4, 7], [11, 13], [15, 21]]

[[3, 4], [5,12], [23, 25]]
```

I want an output like this.

```
[[1, 2], [3,13], [15, 21], [23, 25]]
```

Anybody can help me?

Comment: And how is the output determined? I fail to see the pattern. How do `[3, 4]`, `[4, 7]` and `[11, 13]` become `[3, 13]`?

Comment: can;t understand exactly how you want that ouuput? Where did the number 5, 12 go?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merging a list of time-range tuples that have overlapping time-ranges](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679638/merging-a-list-of-time-range-tuples-that-have-overlapping-time-ranges); the accepted answer works perfectly for your expected output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The algorithm from [Merging a list of time-range tuples that have overlapping time-ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679638/merging-a-list-of-time-range-tuples-that-have-overlapping-time-ranges) works perfectly for your input, provided you concatenate them:

```
def merge(times):
    saved = list(times[0])
    for st, en in sorted([sorted(t) for t in times]):
        if st <= saved[1]:
            saved[1] = max(saved[1], en)
        else:
            yield tuple(saved)
            saved[0] = st
            saved[1] = en
    yield tuple(saved)

lst1 = [[1, 2], [4, 7], [11, 13], [15, 21]]
lst2 = [[3, 4], [5,12], [23, 25]]

print list(merge(sorted(lst1 + lst2)))
```

output:

```
[(1, 2), (3, 13), (15, 21), (23, 25)]
```

Comment: It does not work if `lst1` and `lst2` is swapped -- the first item has to be the "smallest" for `merge` to work correctly.

Comment: @lazyr: and extra sort solves that. :-)

Comment: +1 for guessing what the question is.