# To covert a set of overlapping ranges into nonoverlapping ranges?

Tags: python, algorithm, range

Consider the example:

```
a = [[95.958, 101.566], [117.665, 121.995], [138.909, 153.961],
     [154.529, 252.391], [229.633, 232.087], [268.995, 269.266],
     [269.432, 283.028], [286.432, 364.575], [366.179, 437.013],
     [446.27, 601.232], [585.713, 1374.37], [1287.678, 2464.882], 
     [2273.926, 5218.017]]
```

Based on the above array elements

```
[446.27, 601.232], [585.713, 1374.37], 
[1287.678, 2464.882], [2273.926, 5218.017]
```

These overlap with each-other. So to from an non-overlapping range these elements become a single element

```
[446.27, 5218.017]
```

so the final array will become

```
a = [[95.958, 101.566], [117.665, 121.995], [138.909, 153.961],
     [154.529, 252.391], [229.633, 232.087], [268.995, 269.266], 
     [269.432, 283.028], [286.432, 364.575], [366.179, 437.013],
     [446.27,5218.017]]
```

if anyone could suggest a code to do this in python it will be helpful?

Comment: Is this a list of ranges? And you want to merge overlapping ranges?

Comment: @vz0 each element of array i,e [95.958, 101.566] is a range from 95.958 sec to 101.566 sec.Yes i want to merge overlapping ranges

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merging a list of time-range tuples that have overlapping time-ranges](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679638/merging-a-list-of-time-range-tuples-that-have-overlapping-time-ranges)

Answer (score 0):

Let your `left` hand and `right` hand reference one item at a time, and an `output` list for the merge result.

1. Starting with the first element on the sequence, pick it with your `left` hand.
2. Pick the next one in your `right` hand.
3. Check if your `left` hand overlaps with your `right` hand:

   - If they overlap, merge your `left` hand with your `right` hand and keep it with your `left` hand
   - If no overlap, add your `left` hand item to the `output` list, and move your `right` hand to your `left` hand.
4. Goto 2 until no more items remains.
5. If your `left` hand has an item, add it to the `output`.