# python merging pairs lists within sublists within a list by comparing previous pair's second number with next pair's first number

Tags: python, list, for-loop, merge, comparison

```
[[[0, 2], [2, 9]], [[3, 7], [7, 9], [9, 12], [15, 17]], [[4, 6]]]
```

I need to iterate through this list of sublists of list pairs and check whether the next pair in the sublist has its first number same as the second number of the previous pair. If it is the same, merge.

So what it needs to do is merge `[0, 2]` and `[2, 9]` to get `[0, 9]` and merge ONLY `[3, 7],[7, 9],[9, 12]` to get `[3, 12]` but don't touch `[15, 17]`, so the second sublist sublist will end up becoming `[[3, 12], [15, 17]]`
and finally the main list becomes:

```
[[[0, 9]], [[3, 12], [15, 17]], [[4, 6]]]
```

How do I do that? I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
def merge(lst_of_lsts):
    res = []
    for sublist in lst_of_lsts:
        for i, ressublists in enumerate(res):
            if sublist[1]==ressublists[0]:
                res[i] += ([sublist[0],ressublists[-1]])
                break
        else:
            res.append(sublist)
    return res
```

Comment: This looks applicable: [Merging a list of time-range tuples that have overlapping time-ranges](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5679638)

Comment: So how does that function not work? What output did you get? Did you get any errors (give us the full traceback). Help us help you!

Comment: I tried it on merge([[0, 4], [4, 8]]) and got the same. No merging. =(

Comment: Again, please add that to the question; in comments it is going to get lost. Give us a short section on how you called it, what happened, and what you expected instead.

Comment: "No merging" is not helpful information. To assist you we need to know what the program is supposed to do (which you have described very well indeed) and what it's actually doing (which you've hardly described at all). Please run your program (which as given does nothing but define a function) and include the output in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the link above:

```
def merge(times):
    saved = list(times[0])
    for st, en in sorted([sorted(t) for t in times]):
        if st <= saved[1]:
            saved[1] = max(saved[1], en)
        else:
            yield list(saved)
            saved[0] = st
            saved[1] = en
    yield list(saved)

>>>mylist = [[[0, 2], [2, 9]], [[3, 7], [7, 9], [9, 12], [15, 17]], [[4, 6]]]
>>>[list(merge(i)) for i in mylist]
[[[0, 9]], [[3, 12], [15, 17]], [[4, 6]]]
```

Comment: Please modify it for you. Just copy pasted :)

Comment: @iteong: if an answer already exists please link to it rather than copying the code - SO tries to avoid duplicate questions. Thanks!